# How to use memset to add colours to a pixel array?

Tags: c, sdl, pixel, sdl-2, memset

I have a program in C and SDL2 with a pixel array:

```
Uint32 *pixels = NULL;
pixels = (Uint32 *) malloc (sizeof(Uint32)*(Uint32)windowWidth*(Uint32)windowHeight);
memset(pixels, 255, (Uint32)windowWidth*(Uint32)windowHeight*sizeof(Uint32));
```

With memset, making my second parameter '255' sets all the pixels to white. Every other number below that sets the pixels to a shade of grey. How do I set these pixels to an actual colour?

I use this pixel array to set screen colour via the texture amongst other things. The texture has a pixel format of `ARGB8888` so a four colour channel Hex value should work, no?

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, (int)((Uint32)windowWidth * sizeof(Uint32)));
```

I have tried using hex such as `0xFFCC00FF` but that just sets it to white.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `memset` is that it copies the same value to each byte. You want to use `memcpy` in a loop with a 4-byte value.

```
Uint32 numPixels = (Uint32)windowWidth * (Uint32)windowHeight;
Uint32 color = (Uint32)0xFFCC00FF;
for (Uint32 i = 0; i < numPixels; ++i)
{
    memcpy(pixels + i * sizeof(Uint32), &color, sizeof(color));
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why, but this created thin coloured lines over the texture rather than a solid colour texture. I did use your answer as a starting point though so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
Uint32 *pixels = NULL;
size_t nPixels = windowWidth * windowHeight;
pixels = malloc (sizeof (Uint32) * nPixels);
for (size_t c = 0; c < nPixels; c++) {
    pixels[c] = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use memset but thanks to @Banex I was able to come up with something that worked.

```
Uint32 colour = (Uint32)0xFFCC00FF;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<windowWidth;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<windowHeight;j++)
    {
        pixels[i+j*windowWidth]=colour;
    }
}
```